# Whats the IE6 same origin policy

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

Here is a useful page detailing the specification for the same origin policy in Mozilla.

[Same origin policy for Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Does anyone know or have a link to information of how the same origin policy in IE6.

Primarily I would like to know if websites are operating from differnt ports then would they be considered to be from the same origin or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Primarily I would like to know if websites are operating from differnt ports then would they be considered to be from the same origin or not?

See the [browser security handbook](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy) for a detailed comparison. IE, as the only browser, does **not** seem to be sensitive of the port number:

> If protocol, host name, and - for browsers other than Microsoft Internet Explorer - port number for two interacting pages match, access is granted with no further checks.

Comment: Thanks, thats a useful document.  What do I have to do to get an up vote round here